# element wise checking of nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists, elementwise-operations

Check nested list elementwise for multiple conditions and return 0 or 1 if condition is not met or is met.

I have to check

at least 14

cannot be equal to= 19

if the element ends in 4 or 9

For example, age array of

```
[[22, 13, 31, 13],
 [17, 14, 24, 22]]
```

will have the output array as

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

I've tried flattening the list and then checking each condition, but it's not working.

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in age for item in sublist]
x=14
[not x for x in flat_list]
```

Comment: what do you mean by `at least 14 != 19` ?

Comment: Are you trying to check if the values are not equal to `x`?

Comment: Also, `not 14` will return `False`, because `14` behaves as `True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a faster numpy solution:

```
((arr >= 14) & (arr != 19) & ((arr%10 == 4) | (arr%10==9))).astype(int)
```

**Code**:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[22, 13, 31, 13],
                [17, 14, 24, 22]])

print(((arr >= 14) & (arr != 19) & ((arr%10 == 4) | (arr%10==9))).astype(int))

# [[0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 1 0]]
```

Comment: thank you! this is the answer: 
print (((arr%10 == 4) | (arr%10 == 9) & (arr >= 14) & (arr != 19)).astype(int))

Comment: @C.Nivs, the requirement was a slightly unclear for me, thanks. By re-casting, do you mean converting to 1s and 0s? Those logical operations yield an array of trues and falses which are nothing but analogous to 1s and 0s. (To note that boolean is subclass of int.)

Comment: @Austin yeah, that was the question, but I found that in the docs shortly before you replied. Thanks, though!

Comment: @Austin I ran some profiling against my code, and out of curiosity, profiled the `numpy` implementation as well, and wound up with numpy being slower than the `map` implementation. `python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; arr = np.array([[22, 13, 31, 13],[17, 14, 24, 22]])' '((arr >= 14) & (arr != 19) & ((arr%10 == 4) | (arr%10==9))).astype(int)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.53 usec per loop`. I can't quite wrap my head around that one, as I'd imagine `numpy` would blow the `map` implementation out of the water (this is python 3.6, numpy 1.16.2)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with list comprehensions like so:

```py
somelist = [[22, 13, 31, 13],
 [17, 14, 24, 22]]

result = [[1 if (x%10==4 or x%10==9) and (x>=14 and x!=19) else 0 for x in sublist] for sublist in somelist]

result
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Where `x%10` will get the last digit in each number, allowing the direct comparison. By grouping the two conditions, you can more logically lay out what you want to do, though this gets a bit messy for a list comprehension.

A better way (at the potential expense of speed) might be to use `map`:

```py
def check_num(num):
    value_check = num >= 14 and num != 19
    last_num_check = num % 10 == 4 or num % 10 == 9
    return int(value_check and last_num_check)

somelist = [[22, 13, 31, 13],
 [17, 14, 24, 22]]

result = [[x for x in map(check_num, sublist)] for sublist in somelist]

result
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Timing the difference between operations:

### List Comprehension

```py
python -m timeit -s 'somelist = [[22, 13, 31, 13], [17, 14, 24, 22]]' '[[1 if (x%10==4 or x%10==9) and (x>=14 and x!=19) else 0 for x in sublist] for sublist in somelist]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.35 usec per loop
```

### Map

```py
python -m timeit -s 'from somefunc import check_num; somelist = [[22, 13, 31, 13], [17, 14, 24, 22]]' '[[x for x in map(check_num, sublist)] for sublist in somelist]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.37 usec per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! This works: [[1 if x%10==4 or x%10==9 and x>=14 and x!=19  else 0 for x in sublist] for sublist in X]  HOWEVER it doesn't pass because the solution doesn't compile fast enough...it has to be faster than a certain threshold

Comment: @JuliaDills Then I would definitely look at @Austin 's solution, as `numpy's` vectorized operations could potentially be much quicker

Answer (score 0):

Just for your example it can be done with a bit of mapping.

The way you can verify that the last digit equals to a number is by applying a modulo-10 on the number.

```
my_list = [[22, 13, 31, 13],[17, 14, 24, 22]]

result_list = []
for sublist in my_list:
    result_list.append(list(map(lambda x: 1 if x % 10 == 4 and x >= 14 and x != 19 else 0, sublist)))

print(result_list)
```

will yield:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

C.Nvis has a good answer with list comprehension. You can also solve this using nested for loops

```
def is_valid(x):
    return (x == 14) or (x%10 == 4) or (x%10 == 9)

out = []

for sublist in matrix:
    out_sublist = []
    for i in sublist:
        if (is_valid(i)):
            out_sublist.append(1)
        else:
            out_sublist.append(0)
    out.append(out_sublist)

print(out)
```

These answers are effectively the same algorithm.